# SQL Server 2008: performance cost for a single sql statement

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, sql-execution-plan

I have 2 stored procedures which I want to compare and identify which of them requires less resources and performs better. The second procedure is a modification of the first procedure and it contains slightly changed sql statements of the first procedure. My goal is to understand the impact of the changes in terms of query cost.

In order to do so, I execute each procedure separately with an option "Include actual execution plan" and analyse both execution plans. My problem is that I cannot say which sql query performs better in a simple manner.

For example consider the following execution plan of the query of the first stored procedure:

[image]

The plan shows that the query cost is *0% relative to the batch* and *Clustered Index Seek* operator is 100% relative to the query. I have the same numbers for the corresponding query of the second procedure Unfortunately this is  not enough to understand which query has the minimal cost.

Therefore, my question: is there a way to determine the cost of the whole query. The best would be the table with a query and its particular cost, e.g. CPU cost or I/O cost.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `SET STATISTICS IO ON` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184361.aspx) and `SET STATISTICS TIME ON` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190287.aspx) before running both procedures. It will show additional info about time and input/output. Remember that results of procedures can be cached, plans can be cached, so you have to do it carefully, before making any conclussions. First run can always be slower than next ones. You should clean your cache with `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` and `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`, before making any tests. You should also read about differences between clustered and non-clustered index, seek and scan and other actions presented in plan.

Comment: @LukLed: Thanks for the answer, I find the tips useful. However, the question remains open: are there some system tables which allows one to see exact cost values for the query.

Comment: @LukLed: In your opinion why it worth to analyse query cost with cleaned cache plan? The execution plan is reused by SQL Server most of the time, isn't it?

Comment: @Tim - the exact cost is variable, so having it in a table would not make sense, so I think your best bet is to use this suggestion or to run your query hundreds of times and get statistics on how long it took per query and in the aggregate, in order to compare.

Comment: @Tim - This information is available (aggregated) via `sys.dm_exec_query_stats` but I would much rather just use profiler or `SET STATISTICS ... ON` or show client statistics option in SSMS

Comment: @Tim - If your data changes a great deal then analyzing with a cleaned cache makes sense.  It depends on which is more likely to be the normal use case, as, if you assume it will be cached, and it won't actually be, then your numbers will be wrong. By assuming no cache you have a worst-case.

Comment: @Tim: If you do it right, it will be reused. It is worth checking if it is. SQL Server has DMV view (sys.dm_exec_query_stats, sys.dm_exec_sql_text), that allow you to check query performance.

Comment: @James: "the exact cost is a variable" that is right, and it would be great to know each of them for every query of the stored procedure, therefore, table would suite for this purpose well. Btw, I have found the exact number showing the query cost of the query including both IO and CPU, but it is in execution plan and it is not so handy to point the mouse on it every time. The variable is called: *Estimated subtree cost*

Comment: @LukLed, @James: the note about how the plan is reused makes a lot of sense, it is better to know the worst case, then underestimate the cost with the cached plan.

Comment: @LukLed, before using `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` Microsoft suggests to utilize `CHECKPOUNT` in order to make all dirty buffers clean.

Comment: @LukLed: I mark your answer as the solution, because I like your suggestion about cleaning plan and data caches. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can trace the queries in SQL profiler. There you get CPU, IO, Total time, etc for each query you run.

Comment: very nice suggestion +1. Do know how one can get statistics about physical reads in the SQL Profiler? There is READS counter which only unfortunately shows logical reads.